# Conditional update all documents in all CosmosDB partitions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a CosmosDb container that have (simplified) documents like this:

```
{
    id,
    city,
    propertyA,
    propertyB
}
```

The partitionkey is 'city'.
Usually this works well. But there has been a bug in our code and now I have to update a lot of documents in a lot of different partitions.

I made a conditional update document like so:

```
{
  "conditions": "from c where propertyA = 1",
  "operations": [
    {
      "op": "set"
      "path": "/propertyB",
      "value": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This document I send with the REST API to CosmosDB

Because I want to update all documents in all partitions that satisfy the condition I set the x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition header to 'True'.
But I still need to supply a partition key in the x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey header.

Is there a way to use the REST API to update all the documents for which the condition is true, whatever the partitionkey is?

Comment: are you using SDK or REST API?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way through which REST API can provide us with the **ability to create, query, and delete databases, collection of documents, and documents through programmatically**. `To change a document partially, you can use the PATCH HTTP Method.`

You will still need to supply a partition key in the **x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey header**.

***If you have created the document based on partition key, you must need to provide partition key in header.***

For more information regarding the above said partition key, you can refer the below documentation link: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/patch-a-document**

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had found this link. That is why I tried it to update all documents in all partitions that satisfy a condition. As you, when using this method you still need to supply a partionkey. In my case there are many 1000 of them. as there are many cities.  Therefore I am looking for a way that updates all documents in all partitions. Is there a way to do this? (other than just writing e.g. an Azure Function)

Comment: the OP was asking how to do that for all partition keys at once without creating an azure function or some other special solution